# How can I fill in spaces between lines without overlapping?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I wanted to fill in the space between the following lines, however some of the spaces seem to over lap. Is there a way to disable the overlapping shaded regions? In the image the overlapped region is a little darker. Is there a way to get rid of that.

The code is an example of what I want, in reality there would be many lines

```
x = np.linspace(0,6,100)
y1 = np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x)
y2 = np.exp(-x)*np.cos(x) + np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x)
y3 =np.exp(-x)*np.cos(-x) + np.exp(-x)*np.sin(-x)


plt.plot(x,y1,'k')
plt.plot(x,y2,'k')
plt.plot(x,y3,'k')


plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2,color='m',alpha=0.2)
plt.fill_between(x, y2, y3,color='m',alpha=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to shade the region between the lowermost and uppermost line. I've changed your code slightly to use an array for the lines, which makes it easier to do things all at once. Notice how this simplifies both the call to the initial black line plot and the idea of taking the maximum and minimum over that array's columns.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,6,100)
ys = np.array([
    np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x),
    np.exp(-x)*np.cos(x) + np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x),
    np.exp(-x)*np.cos(-x) + np.exp(-x)*np.sin(-x),
])

plt.plot(x, ys.T, 'k')

plt.fill_between(x, np.min(ys, axis=0), np.max(ys, axis=0), color='m', alpha=0.2)

plt.show()
```

Results in this plot:

[image: Lines and magenta fill showing shading between min and max line]

Answer (score 1):

You set the alpha value to make the color lighter, but this makes it also transparent. You can just use HEX color values with alpha 0.

```
x = np.linspace(0,6,100)
y1 = np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x)
y2 = np.exp(-x)*np.cos(x) + np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x)
y3 =np.exp(-x)*np.cos(-x) + np.exp(-x)*np.sin(-x)


plt.plot(x,y1,'k')
plt.plot(x,y2,'k')
plt.plot(x,y3,'k')


plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2,color='#ffccff')
plt.fill_between(x, y2, y3,color='#ffccff')

plt.show()
```